# InitialValue isn't working properly in Multi-Select package Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

so I am using `MultiSelectBottomSheetField` in this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter). I posted on their github as well as an issue but it seems fairly inactive so i came here looking for help.

And I am having some issues with the initialValue parameter for it. So at the moment, I have data saved in firestore as a string but its in the format of a list. And what i was trying to do was get the string data from firestore -> convert to a list with the respective class -> and then show as initial value in the above package/widget. But whats happening is that the initial value isnt showing, even though the value is not empty.

So for context this is how I change to list from firestore string:

```dart
  List<Skill?> skillList = [];
  void changeSkillToList(String? stringList) {
    int indexOfOpenBracket = stringList!.indexOf("[");
    int indexOfLastBracket = stringList.lastIndexOf("]");
    var noBracketString =
        stringList.substring(indexOfOpenBracket + 1, indexOfLastBracket);
    var list = noBracketString.split(", ");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      skillList.add(Skill(id: 1, name: list[i].toString()));
    }
  }
```

this is how i use the acc widget:

```dart
 final _skillItems =
    skill.map((skill) => MultiSelectItem<Skill>(skill, skill.name)).toList();

MultiSelectBottomSheetField<Skill?>(
selectedColor: Color(0xFF5DB075),
selectedItemsTextStyle:
    TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
initialChildSize: 0.4,
decoration: BoxDecoration(),
listType: MultiSelectListType.CHIP,
initialValue: skillList,
searchable: true,
items: _skillItems,
buttonText: Text("Select your skills...",
    style: GoogleFonts.inter(
        color: Color(0xFFBDBDBD),
        fontSize: 16)),
onConfirm: (values) {
  context
      .read(pharmacistSignUpProvider.notifier)
      .changeSkillList(values);
},
chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
  items: context
      .read(pharmacistSignUpProvider.notifier)
      .skillList
      ?.map((e) =>
          MultiSelectItem(e, e.toString()))
      .toList(),
  chipColor: Color(0xFF5DB075),
  onTap: (value) {
    context
        .read(
            pharmacistSignUpProvider.notifier)
        .skillList
        ?.remove(value);
    return context
        .read(
            pharmacistSignUpProvider.notifier)
        .skillList;
  },
  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
),
),
```

And this is my initState:

```dart
  List<Skill?> skillList = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    skillList = changeSkillToList(context
        .read(pharmacistMainProvider.notifier)
        .userDataMap?["knownSkills"]);
    print(skillList);
    super.initState();
  }
```

If someone could help me out, it would be very appreciated. Let me know if you guys have any questions

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I get some problem and I fix it by adding the == operator to my entity in your case skill

```
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return other is Skill && this.id == other.id;
  }
```

inside your **Skill** class